# Add a pause to an animated camera (following curve path)

Tags: animation, camera, bezier-curves, keyframes

I'm new to Blender.  I'm running the latest (2.74).  I have made a complex scene, with a camera following a Curve Path.  I would simply like to stop the camera from moving, from time to time, to allow the viewer to take a good look at whatever the camera is pointing at, then continue along the path.  I have searched and searched and tried a few tutorials, but nothing works for me.  I'm missing a simple procedure, I know!  I've read about doing animation all with keyframes instead of following a path, which seem to make it easier to have control, but I don't want to re-invent my complex path.

I have tried messing the inserting keyframes manually into the timeline and then editing them in the Dope Sheet but failed miserably.

Comment: You can use Graph Editor to achieve that. After animating path select it, it has Evaluation time property, going to infinity. In N panel, Modifiers scroll add Limits modifier and activate Minimum X and Maximum X checkboxes. Now you can animate values below checkboxes and get as smooth pauses as slow animation of values will be. [Very simple version](http://i.imgur.com/gYegWGY.gif)

Comment: @MrZak Should be an answer, not a comment. Comments are for clarification of the issue.

Comment: @RayMairlot I didn't have enough time to post it. Also, after testing it I saw it wasn't really answer - it works for pausing movement, not for resuming

Comment: @MrZak I don't understand your solution at all.  I'd ask you to provide some specific steps that I could follow, but your 2nd comment seems to indicate that it is not really going to work for me anyway?

Comment: 1. It's rather easy to achieve pausing camera with solution in that accepted answer. After turning on `Fixed Position`, you should animate the `Offset` value. That's where values 0,.0.5, 1 come from - value 0 of that offset means the beginning of the path, 1 - end. 2. I remade my solution and it *may* work, but it's lot more difficult to set up. And because of presence of easier solution I didn't add mine

Comment: @atreyu please do not edit your *question* to include the *answer*.

Comment: oh my god, your rules.  just delete this, forget it.